# Finding resistive force for an object falling in a medium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

Hello there fellow users, i would like to ask a question related to the topic above. if an object is falling in liquid, or any other medium such as air, how would one calculate the resistive force? provided you have the objects acceleration as say, X. How would one construct an equation to solve such a question?

Comment: um.... kind of like F=mg-ma?

Answer (score 0):

Solve for the ideal acceleration due to gravity g (or, at Earth's surface, use $g=-9.81 m/s^2$). Measure the actual acceleration X. Subtract. Newton's first law gives the force F resisting the motion must be $F=ma$ where $a=X-g$.